# Binomial coefficients identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Prove this identity:
$$\binom {N-1/2} {N-1}=\frac{N}{4^{N-1}}\binom{2N-1}{N-1}$$

I was not able to find the proof of this

Comment: Did you mean (n-1)/2 on the left hand side?

Comment: You should be aware that throwing a good number of PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) won't probably help your reputation or attract answerers. Anyway that follows by writing both sides in terms of the $\Gamma$ function and applying Legendre's duplication formula. Or just by induction.

Comment: Ok, I'll take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{N-\frac{1}{2}}{N-1}&=\frac{\left(N-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(N-\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdots3}{(N-1)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}\cdot\frac{(2N-1)(2N-3)\cdots 3}{(N-1)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}\cdot\frac{(2N-1)!!}{(N-1)!}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}\cdot\frac{(2N)!}{(N-1)!(2N)!!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}\cdot\frac{(2N)\cdot(2N-1)!}{(N-1)!2^NN!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{N}{4^{N-1}}\binom{2N-1}{N-1}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use *[double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* notation $(2N-1)!!=(2N-1)\cdot(2N-3)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$
- In (2) we use $N!=N!!\cdot(N-1)!!$
- In (3) we use $(2N)!!=2^N\cdot N!$